# Bundle products like this page

Tags: product, image, bundle

I have a magento 2.4 installation and I'm looking for a products bundle page like the one in cremelondon, https://cremelondon.com/tools/bundle-builder/9zWm/new.
there the customer have to select 6 products at total, they will select with a - and + button, it can be mixed or 1 of each kind, the price does not change. Plus, each product has its own photo.
Could someone please help me or does anybody some module?
Thank you.